# Can not get the element to be at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

Basically the idea is that I have a picture galery and at the bottom there should be a load more bar. I have tried a lot of different options of using the bottom tag but somehow the element always stays right after the div that is above him. What should I change to make it work?

```
   .portfolio_bottom {
        padding: 2em 0;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
    }


<body>
   <div class="portfolio s1" id="portfolio">
     <div class="portfolio_box">
        <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
           <a href="#" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  thickbox">
            <img src="images/p1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                <div class="b-wrapper">
                   <h2 class="b-animate b-from-left    b-delay03 ">
                     <img src="images/p_logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                     <span>Cerkve</span>
                     <button>Odpri galerijo</button>
                     <label> &#x1f4c5  10.6.2016 </label>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="portfolio_bottom">
     <a class="btn3" href="#"><span>Loadmore</span></a>
   </div>


    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What happened, you successfully loaded more files?

Comment: Where is your problem? Have a look at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7hb01of/).

Comment: @Huelfe that is what I have https://jsfiddle.net/oxs7bbjf/ the load more should be at the bottom of the page but I can not get it there

Comment: it's only at down see removing all applied padding

Comment: In your jsfiddle the load more is at the bottom. You are using media queries. If the window is 320px or smaller everything looks ok to me.

Answer (score -1):

Assign `position:relative` to the parent element.

```
#portfolio {position:relative;}
```